# Why can't I access a member of this class?

Tags: c++, class, syntax, initialization, variable-initialization

I have the following three class definitions:

```
class String
{
    public:
        String() {}
        String(const char *) {}
};

class ClassA
{
    public:
        ClassA(const String &) {}
};

class ClassB
{
    public:
        ClassB(const ClassA &, const String & = String()) {}
        void method() {}
};
```

Now suppose I want to create an instance of `ClassB`:

```
String name("test");
ClassA item(ClassB(name));
```

This doesn't work:

```
error: request for member 'method' in 'item', which is of non-class
  type 'ClassA ()(ClassB)'
```

What does this error mean? And what is this strange type `ClassA ()(ClassB)` the compiler keeps referring to?

Comment: Are you sure that's exactly how `item` is declared?

Comment: `ClassA item(ClassB(name));` seems incorrect as `ClassA` doesn't take a type `ClassB` in the constructor, it only takes `String`. `ClassB` doesn't appear to have any valid conversions to `String`. Perhaps this was a typo and you meant `ClassB item(ClassA(name));`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called *most vexing parse problem*.

```
ClassA item(ClassB(name));
```

should either be:

```
ClassB b(name);
ClassA item(b);
```

or:

```
ClassA item( (ClassB(name)) );
```

Also have a look at: [Most vexing parse: why doesn't A a(()); work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1424510/1168156)

Comment: Or: `ClassA item((ClassB(name)));`.

Comment: Why does this make a difference?

Comment: @NathanOsman: see the text of the *question* linked as a duplicate.